# How to copy cell value and paste under previous cell

Tags: excel, copy, vba

I want a macro to copy data from a certain cell, and copy it to a cell on another work sheet, but I'd like it to be a continuous list. I mean, copying the first cell into A2, then the next into A3, and so on. This is the code I've come up with so far, and it works to copy into cell A2, but it erases the previous data.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Copy_Data()
Worksheets("PremakeResults").Range("B1").Copy Worksheets("SavedResults").Range("A2")
End Sub
```

I have a feeling this is a fairly simple macro, but I haven't been looking for the right things on the internet. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I just tried this code

```
Sub Copy_Data()
Worksheets("PremakeResults").Range("B1").Copy Worksheets("SavedResults").Range("A" & Worksheets("SavedResults").Cells(Worksheets("SavedResults").‌​Rows.Count, "A").End(Xlup).Row)
End Sub
```

and while that will copy to the specified page, it still erases over the first entry.

Comment: To copy to the first empty row in Column A `Worksheets("PremakeResults")` use , `Worksheets("PremakeResults").Range("B1").Copy Worksheets("SavedResults").Range("A" & Worksheets("SavedResults").Cells(Worksheets("SavedResults").Rows.Count, "A").End(Xlup).Row)`

Comment: @ShaiRado Hi, I don't want to copy the first empty row, I want to paste into the first empty row in "SavedResults"

Comment: that's what my comment means,paste to the first empty row in column A

Comment: @ShaiRado I copied what you gave my into VBA and it doesn't copy anything anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. 
This finds the last row in the SavedResults sheets column A then adds one to select the next row then it sets the value here to be the same as Cell B1 in the premake results sheet

```
Sub Copy_Data()
Dim LastRow as Variant
LastRow = Worksheets("SavedResults").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Worksheets("SavedResults").Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("PremakeResults").Range("B1").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I just got a compile error, where it says the variable is not defined and it highlights "last row"

Comment: Thank you so much!!